# FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 5: syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE)

Tags: authentication, laravel-5.1

I got stuck with this error written on the title while doing authentication steps on Laravel by following this guide.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/authentication

I have done until creating and copy the code into the *register.blade.php*, but when I get into localhost:8000/auth/login, it will show this error:

> FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 5:
>
> syntax error, unexpected 'private' (T_PRIVATE)

http://localhost:8000 works fine and direct to my home page.This is my AuthController codes on line 5: `private $redirectTo = '/';`

Really needed help here please if anyone know. Thank you very much.

Comment: What is line 4?  (This looks like the error you would get if line 4 was not terminated.) In fact, can edit your answer to include all five lines of the code.

Comment: Could you paste likes 1-5 of your controller class?

Comment: Hi Martin and jed, the 1-5 Line is:
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

private $redirectTo = '/';

It came like this as default inside the Laravel 5.1 project folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, private and protected declarations are not the same,

Change

`private $redirectTo = '/';`

to

`protected $redirectTo = '/';`

Secondly, ensure AuthController.php is a PHP class file with correct namespace. Using protected outside a class could cause this

Comment: Sorry Digitlimit, I tried this but stil get similar error which is:
FatalErrorException in AuthController.php line 5:
syntax error, unexpected 'protected' (T_PROTECTED)